# Get Objects in a json format?

Tags: json, delphi

I wrote the below code in Delphi 2010 to download a JSON string:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  strResult: string;
  listParams: TStringList;
  JO :TJSONObject;
  JV : TJSONValue;
begin
  listParams := TStringList.Create;
  listParams.Add('action=GET');
  listParams.Add('userid=(11,12,13)');
  try
    strResult := idhttp1.Post('http://xxxnet/api/users.php', listParams);
    Memo1.Lines.Text:=strResult;
    JO := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strResult), 0) as TJSONObject;
    JV := JO.Get(0).JsonValue;
    Memo2.Lines.Add(JV.Value);
  finally
    listParams.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When the JSON contains a single object:

```json
{"usertitle":"Mark","userid":"13","username":"950","useremail":"","success":"1","error":""}
```

The code works good.

But when the JSON contains multi objects:

```
[{"usertitle":"Yani","userid":"11","username":"887","useremail":"nili_orusoft@yahoo.com","success":"1","error":""},{"usertitle":"Frank","userid":"12","username":"851","useremail":"","success":"1","error":""},{"usertitle":"Mark","userid":"13","username":"950","useremail":"","success":"1","error":""}]
```

The code crashes with an "access violation at address 00522275" error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You are leaking the object that `ParseJSONValue()` returns.  You need to `Free()` it when you are done using it.
2. Your second JSON example is an array of objects. `ParseJSONValue()` will return a `TJSONArray` instead of a `TJSONObject`, so your `as TJSONObject` typecast will fail and raise an exception (but it should not be raising an access violation).

Try this code instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  strResult: string;
  listParams: TStringList;
  JA: TJSONArray;
  JO: TJSONObject;
  JV, JV2: TJSONValue;
begin
  listParams := TStringList.Create;
  try
    listParams.Add('action=GET');
    listParams.Add('userid=(11,12,13)');
    strResult := idhttp1.Post('http://xxxnet/api/users.php', listParams);
  finally
    listParams.Free;
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Text := strResult;
  JV := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strResult), 0);
  try
    if JV is TJSONObject then
    begin
      JO := TJSONObject(JV);
      JV2 := JO.Get(0).JsonValue;
      Memo2.Lines.Add(JV2.Value);
    end
    else if JV is TJSONArray then
    begin
      JA := TJSONArray(JV);
      JO := JA.Get(0) as TJSONObject;
      JV2 := JO.Get(0).JsonValue;
      Memo2.Lines.Add(JV2.Value);
    end;
  finally
    JV.Free;
  end;
end;
```